# Android cannot align ImageView to top of activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, imageview

For some reason, I'm having difficulty aligning ImageView's to the top of the activities in my Android applications.  For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I was able to get the ImageView to align to the top of the activity with "fitStart", but without that then the imageView wouldn't be all the way at the top.  Now that the ImageView is on top, the ListView isn't directly below it.  Instead, it is a quarter of the screen down.  This is happening on all of my activities, even ones without ListView's.

As a side note, I did remove the system title bars from my activities in AndroidManifest.  However, even when I add them back in, the problem is still occurring.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using RelativeLayout's

Answer (score 0):

hi the problem is that u r using `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` for the imageview which will align the view to the center of the parent layout...

also have look at [this](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/14/how-to-position-views-properly-in-layouts/)

Hope this solves your problem...

Comment: Hm, even when I remove "android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" I am still facing the issue where the ImageView and the ListView will not align to the top of the activity...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe that's because your image has transparent borders? Here is what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case, I am sure that there are no transparent borders.  Nice idea, though!

Comment: Can you please upload your image into your question? I'd like to play with it in my layout...

Comment: Ok, I've used solid colored image in your layout and in my case image is perfectly aligned to the top.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the image that I was using was too large, and after it scaled the problem was occurring. Once I used a smaller image, everything aligned perfectly to the top.  Thanks!